# Как случайно присвоить двум участникам первого списка должность шпион. Необходима возможность выбора количества шпионов

Tags: kotlin

```
fun main() {
    val namePlayer = listOf("Никита", "Кристина", "Владимир", "Дмитрий", "Вячеслав")
    val work = listOf("Дворник", "Бармен", "Оффициант", "Повар")
    val spy = namePlayer.random()
    val spyName = "Шпион"

    for (element in namePlayer) {
        if (element == spy) {
            println("$element - $spyName")
            continue
        }
        val workRandom = work.random()
        println("$element - $workRandom")
    }
}
```

---

Подразобрался. Логика работает, но она не защищена от генерации одинаковых значений. Не подскажете как это предотвратить?

```
fun main() {
    val namePlayer = mutableListOf("Никита", "Кристина", "Владимир", "Дмитрий", "Вячеслав")
    val spyArray = mutableSetOf<String>()
    val work = listOf("Дворник", "Бармен", "Оффициант", "Повар")
    val spyValue = 2
    val spyName = "Шпион"

    repeat(spyValue){
        val spy = namePlayer.random()
        spyArray.add(spy)
        namePlayer.remove(spy)
    }
    for (element in spyArray) {
        println("$element - $spyName")
    }
    for (element in namePlayer) {
        val workRandom = work.random()
        println("$element - $workRandom")
    }
}
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Все уже есть из коробки, изучайте стандартные функции языка.
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/shuffled.html
https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/take.html

```
val randomTwo = namePlayer.shuffled().take(2)
```

Каждый раз вызывая получите новых два случайных.